# Handle button which has drill-down menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a UI that when you right click on a button, it opens a screen with 3 other buttons on it. How do i get the event system to not override the last button clicked (being what i right clicked to open the screen) when i click down on the button that is opened. The only way i can think to do it is to store the button that was right clicked in another variable. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the event system from overriding the last button pressed. So that my code will run off what was right clicked and not the button that was clicked.

Comment: Storing it in a newly made variable works fine i guess. I suppose i dont rly understand the event system.

Comment: I'd do the same. Unity's PointerEventData does not really have a property for the chain of senders. However, you could make your own class with that property and make it a child of PointerEventData. I'm not really sure how would you force Unity to use it instead of the default class though. :/

Comment: "The only way i can think to do it is to store the button that was right clicked in another variable."  of course, obviously.  your three-button-panel would have a component (perhaps "ThreeButtonPanel.cs")  When it is called, and it "opens the panel" - obviously make a note of the "openor button".  Certainly do that. It is completely trivial and the only way to proceed.  (It would be nuts to try to distort the event system for this: *you would have to do what is described here anyway!!*)